# Check PHP version for DirectAdmin running two versions

Tags: php, centos, directadmin

I've got a server running a primary and secondary PHP version (in this case 5 and 7). I'm slowly migrating all sites hosted there to PHP 7. I set the PHP version through the DirectAdmin domain setup options.

My question is, is there a way to list what user is using what PHP version? Either through DirectAdmin, or SSH.

I've tried calling `php --version`, but that just returns the primary PHP version.

I'm looking for a way to get a nice list of active PHP versions.

**Info:**

- CentOS 7
- DirectAdmin 1.50 (with custombuild 2.0)

Comment: It is `$ phpenv versions`, if you were using [phpenv](https://github.com/phpenv/phpenv) to manage php versions, but I guess you are using something different?

Comment: Yes, it's a built-in DirectAdmin feature, I believe. phpenv isn't installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run

```
grep php /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/*/domains/*.conf
```

The output will show you the PHP settings for all domains.

Eg.

```
/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/client1/domains/domain1.org.conf:php=ON
/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/client1/domains/domain1.org.conf:php1_select=2
/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/client1/domains/domain1.org.conf:php2_select=1
/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/client2/domains/domain2.com.conf:php=ON
/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/client2/domains/domain3.net.conf:php=ON
/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/client2/domains/domain3.net.conf:php1_select=1
/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/client2/domains/domain3.net.conf:php2_select=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --list php
```

And for change the php default :

```
update-alternatives --config php
```

you should see something like this:

```
  Sélection   Chemin           Priorité  État
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/php7.0   70        mode automatique
  1            /usr/bin/php5     50        mode manuel
  2            /usr/bin/php5.6   56        mode manuel
  3            /usr/bin/php7.0   70        mode manuel
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working this way. `update-alternatives --list php` gives no results.

Comment: is there an error message or is there just no return?

Comment: The top command gives me the usage directions, as it shows there are no arguments for `--list`, and when just using list, it doesn't show PHP. Using `--config` gives me nothing.